# activemq jdbc performance / delays

Tags: java, performance, jdbc, jms, activemq-classic

I'm testing activemq with jdbc store and while I'm aware that it's not the most efficient approach, I see very weird delays.

The code basically fills a queue with 3k messages and then single consumer consumes all of them.
Messages are persistent, acknowledge mode is AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE. I also disabled alwaysSessionAsync and dispatchAsync.

The issue is that consumption speed varies a lot. Here's how long it takes to consume 100 messages (30x to consume it all):

```
2014-07-16 01:08:50,171  'consumer': 45.1 ms
2014-07-16 01:08:50,207  'consumer': 35.5 ms
2014-07-16 01:08:50,290  'consumer': 83.4 ms
2014-07-16 01:08:50,412  'consumer': 122 ms
2014-07-16 01:08:50,476  'consumer': 63.1 ms
2014-07-16 01:08:50,552  'consumer': 75.6 ms
2014-07-16 01:08:50,606  'consumer': 54.5 ms
2014-07-16 01:08:50,655  'consumer': 48.7 ms
2014-07-16 01:08:50,709  'consumer': 53.2 ms
2014-07-16 01:08:50,765  'consumer': 56.2 ms
2014-07-16 01:08:50,813  'consumer': 48.2 ms
2014-07-16 01:08:50,922  'consumer': 109 ms
2014-07-16 01:08:51,188  'consumer': 266 ms
2014-07-16 01:08:51,446  'consumer': 257 ms
2014-07-16 01:08:51,724  'consumer': 278 ms
2014-07-16 01:08:51,975  'consumer': 252 ms
2014-07-16 01:08:52,224  'consumer': 249 ms
2014-07-16 01:08:52,496  'consumer': 271 ms
2014-07-16 01:08:52,743  'consumer': 247 ms
2014-07-16 01:08:52,998  'consumer': 255 ms
2014-07-16 01:08:53,255  'consumer': 257 ms
2014-07-16 01:08:53,486  'consumer': 231 ms
2014-07-16 01:08:53,710  'consumer': 224 ms
2014-07-16 01:08:53,947  'consumer': 236 ms
2014-07-16 01:08:54,189  'consumer': 242 ms
2014-07-16 01:08:54,389  'consumer': 200 ms
2014-07-16 01:08:54,598  'consumer': 209 ms
2014-07-16 01:08:54,790  'consumer': 192 ms
2014-07-16 01:08:54,985  'consumer': 195 ms
2014-07-16 01:08:55,203  'consumer': 217 ms
```

So I enabled logging on TRACE level to find out if there's anything interesting and indeed, there are gaps:

```
2014-07-16 00:34:14,117 ActiveMQ BrokerService[broker_jdbc] Task-1 DEBUG || org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue - QUEUE2 toPageIn: 200, Inflight: 999, pagedInMessages.size 1214, pagedInPendingDispatch.size 214, enqueueCount: 3000, dequeueCount: 386, memUsage:1459248
2014-07-16 00:34:14,117 ActiveMQ BrokerService[broker_jdbc] Task-1 TRACE || org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue - Subscription full QueueSubscription: consumer=ID:LAPTOP-50558-1405488840024-5:1:1:1, destinations=1, dispatched=1000, delivered=0, pending=0
2014-07-16 00:34:14,117 ActiveMQ BrokerService[broker_jdbc] Task-1 TRACE || org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner - Running task iteration 572 - queue://QUEUE2, subscriptions=1, memory=1%, size=5771, in flight groups=null
2014-07-16 00:34:14,117 ActiveMQ BrokerService[broker_jdbc] Task-1 DEBUG || org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue - QUEUE2 toPageIn: 200, Inflight: 999, pagedInMessages.size 1214, pagedInPendingDispatch.size 214, enqueueCount: 3000, dequeueCount: 386, memUsage:1459248
2014-07-16 00:34:14,117 ActiveMQ BrokerService[broker_jdbc] Task-1 TRACE || org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue - Subscription full QueueSubscription: consumer=ID:LAPTOP-50558-1405488840024-5:1:1:1, destinations=1, dispatched=1000, delivered=0, pending=0
2014-07-16 00:34:14,117 ActiveMQ BrokerService[broker_jdbc] Task-1 TRACE || org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner - Running task iteration 573 - queue://QUEUE2, subscriptions=1, memory=1%, size=5771, in flight groups=null
2014-07-16 00:34:14,117 ActiveMQ BrokerService[broker_jdbc] Task-1 DEBUG || org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue - QUEUE2 toPageIn: 200, Inflight: 999, pagedInMessages.size 1214, pagedInPendingDispatch.size 214, enqueueCount: 3000, dequeueCount: 386, memUsage:1459248
2014-07-16 00:34:14,117 ActiveMQ BrokerService[broker_jdbc] Task-1 TRACE || org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue - Subscription full QueueSubscription: consumer=ID:LAPTOP-50558-1405488840024-5:1:1:1, destinations=1, dispatched=1000, delivered=0, pending=0
2014-07-16 00:34:14,117 ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:50562@50559 TRACE || org.apache.activemq.broker.region.PrefetchSubscription - ack: MessageAck {commandId = 392, responseRequired = false, ackType = 2, consumerId = ID:LAPTOP-50558-1405488840024-5:1:1:1, firstMessageId = ID:LAPTOP-50488-1405487850038-3:1:1:1:2017, lastMessageId = ID:LAPTOP-50488-1405487850038-3:1:1:1:2017, destination = queue://QUEUE2, transactionId = null, messageCount = 1, poisonCause = null}
2014-07-16 00:34:14,397 ActiveMQ BrokerService[broker_jdbc] Task-1 TRACE || org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner - Running task iteration 574 - queue://QUEUE2, subscriptions=1, memory=1%, size=5771, in flight groups=null
2014-07-16 00:34:14,397 ActiveMQ BrokerService[broker_jdbc] Task-1 DEBUG || org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue - QUEUE2 toPageIn: 200, Inflight: 998, pagedInMessages.size 1213, pagedInPendingDispatch.size 214, enqueueCount: 3000, dequeueCount: 387, memUsage:1458216
2014-07-16 00:34:14,397 ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:50562@50559 TRACE || org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue - ack of ID:LAPTOP-50488-1405487850038-3:1:1:1:2017 with MessageAck {commandId = 392, responseRequired = false, ackType = 2, consumerId = ID:LAPTOP-50558-1405488840024-5:1:1:1, firstMessageId = ID:LAPTOP-50488-1405487850038-3:1:1:1:2017, lastMessageId = ID:LAPTOP-50488-1405487850038-3:1:1:1:2017, destination = queue://QUEUE2, transactionId = null, messageCount = 1, poisonCause = null}
2014-07-16 00:34:14,397 ActiveMQ BrokerService[broker_jdbc] Task-1 TRACE || org.apache.activemq.broker.region.PrefetchSubscription - ID:LAPTOP-50558-1405488840024-5:1:1:1 dispatched: ID:LAPTOP-50534-1405488592270-3:1:1:1:16 - queue://QUEUE2, dispatched: 1387, inflight: 999
2014-07-16 00:34:14,397 ActiveMQ BrokerService[broker_jdbc] Task-1 TRACE || org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue - assigned ID:LAPTOP-50534-1405488592270-3:1:1:1:16 to consumer ID:LAPTOP-50558-1405488840024-5:1:1:1
2014-07-16 00:34:14,397 ActiveMQ Transport: tcp://laptop/127.0.0.1:50559@50562 DEBUG || jmstest.JmsTest2 - consumer recv: ActiveMQTextMessage {commandId = 20, responseRequired = true, messageId = ID:LAPTOP-50534-1405488592270-3:1:1:1:16, originalDestination = null, originalTransactionId = null, producerId = ID:LAPTOP-50534-1405488592270-3:1:1:1, destination = queue://QUEUE2, transactionId = null, expiration = 0, timestamp = 1405488593001, arrival = 0, brokerInTime = 1405488593001, brokerOutTime = 1405488854397, correlationId = null, replyTo = null, persistent = true, type = null, priority = 4, groupID = null, groupSequence = 0, targetConsumerId = null, compressed = false, userID = null, content = org.apache.activemq.util.ByteSequence@1bca52f3, marshalledProperties = null, dataStructure = null, redeliveryCounter = 0, size = 0, properties = null, readOnlyProperties = true, readOnlyBody = true, droppable = false, jmsXGroupFirstForConsumer = false, text = text}
2014-07-16 00:34:14,397 ActiveMQ BrokerService[broker_jdbc] Task-1 TRACE || org.apache.activemq.broker.region.PrefetchSubscription - ID:LAPTOP-50558-1405488840024-5:1:1:1 dispatched: ID:LAPTOP-50534-1405488592270-3:1:1:1:17 - queue://QUEUE2, dispatched: 1388, inflight: 1000
```

Note that 250ms+ delay in the middle.

The questions is - why are there such delays and how to get rid of them? 
Also - why the times are so low at the beginning (below 100ms) and then they raise to ~250ms?
(changing prefetch size moves the point when the performance degrades)

I also noticed that changing acknowledge mode to CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE and not acknowledging messages makes consumer super-fast (20ms/100), but chokes it few times for 20+ seconds.

- code: http://pastebin.com/v3cPpJKi
- config file: http://pastebin.com/EdzrvcRK
- trace one iteration (100 messages): https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/edef32a8a2bdc31ca3ce/raw/gistfile1.txt

Answer (score 1):

I had faced similar issue sometime back. After investigations I figured out we can tune ***Memory Limit*** and ***Prefecth Limit*** parameters to improve performance for such cases.

By default, *memoryLimit*  is set to 1MB in the activemq.xml file. This parameter indicates the amount of data that can be hold in memory by activemq (if this limit is reached, activemq needs to make IO calls to read data from persistent storage which impacts performance).

I suggest you to increase this value and see if it gives any performance gains.

*Prefetch limit* is other parameter which can be tuned to achieve performance gain. The value for this parameter varies depending on queue configuration you have for activemq.

Other option is to use [FileBasedCursor](http://activemq.apache.org/message-cursors.html).

Refer this link and check if it helps. 
[ActiveMQ stops sending messages to Queue Consumer in case of consumer not acknowledging messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972270/activemq-stops-sending-messages-to-queue-consumer-in-case-of-consumer-not-acknow)

Comment: I set memory limit to 100mb, so it's not the case. Prefetch limit affects the performance, but it just shifts the point where it becomes slow. With the default (1000) it becomes slow after 1000-1200 messages. When I increase it to 5000 (and num. of messages to 10k) then it slows down after ~5500 messages. It behaves like if it was not fetching next 5k but fetching them in small increments instead.